# Unidentified euphorbia turning yellow, how can i rescue it?

Tags: plant-care, cactus, roots, damage, euphorbia

This is my first post and I have been looking on several forums where I can discuss plant queries.

I have a couple of questions regarding a euphorbia cactus so please bear with me.

I recently purchased and a euphorbia cactus (If anyone can ID, that'll be great! I don't know what type it is.) I repotted it in a terracotta pot from the plastic container it arrived in.

[image]

It hadn't been a week and I noticed one of the stems (the one on the right in the photo above) was turning yellow and shrivelling up. I dug to discover what I would call a bruise. Didn't seem like it had been overwatered. Anyway I sliced off that section and applied some rooting powder and have left it to scar. Attached a photo; can it be rescued?

[image]

Just today, I dug a bit further today and found another stem turning slightly yellow. I plan to wait another day and if I see the yellowness spreading I will do surgery on it and perhaps on all the other stems, similar to the one I did above.

[image]

Please let me know what all I should be looking into and how can I rescue this. Where I live its considerably hot, sunny, and humid in an otherwise arid region. However I dont think the climate has got to do with it since the plant is locally grown and purchased.

Appreciate any feedback!!